# Named anchor issue in MarkDown when it comes to TOC

Tags: html, anchor, markdown, named

I am having a trouble with the named anchors in MarkDown. First problem was to give cross-references to some headers with the same title. I solved it with the  tag on the related headers.

But, this time the header with the  tag appears exactly the same in the automatically generated table of contents.

For example, my header in MarkDown looks like below:

```
# <a name="real-config"> </a>Configuration
```

And, in table of contents of my document, it is seen as below:

1. Some Heading
2. Some Other Heading
3. a name="real-config> Configuration"
4. Another Heading

I am using:

- MarkDown editor [Mou](http://mouapp.com/)
- [Pandoc](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/)
- [Beautiful Docs](http://beautifuldocs.com/) to generate the document.

I would appreciate any suggestions for this.

Comment: I'm a little bit confused. Are you using *all three* of Mou, Pandoc and Beautiful Docs to generate your documentation? Do you need a solution that will work with all three, or just one of them?

Comment: I am using Mou to author/edit the document. I think Pandoc and Beautiful Docs are performing the background jobs to create my HTML document. I have performed a lot of research on the Internet for a MarkDown solution for this issue, but couldn't find any. Maybe the trouble is related to Pandoc or Beautiful Docs.

Comment: Well, I've never seen this syntax used to generate header identifiers. I'm pretty sure that vanilla Markdown doesn't support them at all, so you'll have to use a Markdown extension. Pandoc supports manual identifiers like `# My heading {#my-heading}`, or it can generate identifiers for *all of* your headings automatically. Would one of those options help you?

Comment: Sure. Let me try. Which MarkDown extension will I have to use?

Comment: For the first, use the `header_attributes` extension. I think the second one should be enabled by default, but if not you can enable `auto_identifiers`.